# dataframe index: 'int' object is not subscriptable error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate the difference between two index values for a dataframe (number of days between first and last index values in dataframe).
I have the following error (below). I was wondering if there is a workaround for this (it seems the below code was working OK for a small dataframe..)? Thanks

```
type(data1.index)
pandas.core.indexes.base.Index


data1.index = pd.to_datetime(data1.index)
type(data1.index)
pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex


d1 = data1.index[-1]
d1
Timestamp('2022-11-02 00:00:00')


d3 = data1.index[1]
d3
Timestamp('2021-10-03 00:00:00')


(d1-d3).days[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:Temp/ipykernel_3208/1081380695.py in <module>
----> 1 (d1-d3).days[0]

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only [`Timedelta.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.days.html), because subtract scalars to scalar `Timedelta`:

```
out = (d1-d3).days
```